# удаление SOCKET из памяти

Tags: c++, winsock

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib" )

void main(){

    WSADATA buff;
    WSAStartup(0x202, &buff);
    SOCKET S;

    while (1){
        S = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        closesocket(S);
    }
}
```

При работе память в диспетчере все растет и растет, как исправить?

Comment: Инициализация нормально проходит? Почему вообще массив символов подсовывыется вместо явного `WSADATA`? Что возвращают `WSAStartup` и `socket`? У меня аналогичный код память не жрет.

Comment: С инициализацией косяк у Вас однозначно. У меня `sizeof(WSADATA)` вернул 400, т.е. 100 байт явно маловато.

Comment: @alexolut, инициализацию исправил, утечку это не исправило,  WSAStartup возвращает 0, socket в цикле возвращает 2 значения, работать с сокетом можно нормально, единственный косяк это утечка...

Comment: что значит 2 значения? Попеременно разные идентификаторы? Какая версия винды и что за компилятор?

Comment: @alexolut, попеременно разные идентификаторы, win 7, vs13

Comment: В коде точно нет чего-то еще, что может жрать память? Попробуйте подсчитать сколько байт отъедается за итерацию, это может помочь прояснить проблему. Для чистоты эксперимента хорошо бы увидеть полный код программы.

Comment: @alexolut, изменил код

Comment: А если попробовать вставить задержку перед созданием нового сокета? Созданные в TCP-стеке управляющие структуры могут удаляться не сразу после закрытия сокета.

Comment: @KonstantinLes, при секундной задержке тоже утечка, только медленнее идет, я наблюдал за процессом около 5 минут, память все растет и растет, я менял сокет на udp результат тот же

Comment: VS 15, win 7, память не жрет. Попробуйте посмотреть в отладчике, чем память засоряется, ну и посмотрите, что возвращает `closesocket`.

Comment: @Kopkan Тогда я бы попробовал измерить "время жизни" одного сокета: создаём, закрываем и не выходим из программы до нажатия кнопки, наблюдая при этом за памятью. И посмотреть возвращаемое `closesocket` на самом деле не помешало бы.

Comment: @KonstantinLes, `closesocket` возвращает 0, создал 10к сокетов, закрыл, ждал минут 30, память не уменьшилась, расход на это 10к был около 8 мб

Comment: @Kopkan Попробовал в GNU/Linux - проблем с памятью не заметил. Других идей у меня нет - только то, что закрытие сокета на Вашем компьютере происходит медленнее, чем создание нового (предполагаю, что `closesocket` не просто освобождает память, а сообщает сетевому стеку, что нужно закрыть сокет).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае сбоил socket модуль, помогло `netsh winsock reset`